# Laravel model item set carbon item but returns string

Tags: laravel, datetime, types, php-carbon

I have added a datetime in the database schema:

```php
$table->dateTime('send_at')->nullable();
```

I have set the attribute to a Carbon instance in the seeder:

```php
$invoice->send_at = Carbon::now();
```

When I try to get the type of the attribute inside the controller it returns a string:

```php
dd(gettype($data['invoices'][0]->send_at));
```

What is going on? And how can I be sure that it's a Carbon Object instead of a string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On your model, you need to define `$dates` property to create Carbon instance automatically for the column :

```
protected $dates = ['send_at'];
```

On Since Laravel 8:

```
protected $casts = [
    'send_at' => 'datetime',
];
```

Comment: You are my hero! Thanks! Just another question: why isn't that necessary for the created_at and updated_at attributes?

Comment: `created_at` and `updated_at` also a Carbon instance, set by **default** on Laravel itself. So we don't need to define it manually.

Comment: setting $casts is not working for me, it's coming back as string still.